# How to populate a dictionary's value with a list using for loop while?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wonder how to populate a dictionary's value, for example, having a list with 1000 values or even  up to 1000, using for loops while

```
dict = {}

values= [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..,1]

dict={'x':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..,1]}
```

Comment: `dict['x'] = values`? There's no `for` needed to set a value into a dictionary. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I’ll second what @Amadan said, your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'populating' a dictionary you mean adding values to a dictionary, then all you need to do is append to `dict['x']`. `dict` is a reserved name in Python, so I would suggest renaming that. To append 1000 elements to your dictionary, use this code:

```
dict = {'x': []}
for a in range(1000):
    dict['x'].append(1)
```

This is a basic way of doing it. Although, there are much better ways of doing it, and I'm not 100% sure about what you mean by 'populating'. And, as other people have commented, you can just set values in dictionaries manually.

I hope you find a solution to this. :)

Comment: thanks, Aiden Blishen Cuneo, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Please note that you should NOT copy&paste it like this. Naming the variable with name `dict` overwrites the Python default data structure `dict` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)). You should use another variable name like `my_dict` or even better give it a more descriptive name.

Comment: @MeisterEder7 Thanks for pulling me up on that, but I already noted it in my answer: "`dict` is a reserved name in Python, so I would suggest renaming that." - I was simply using the variable name that was given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want to print 1 value at a time. You can also print a particular value by using dict['x'][1]

```
dict = {}

values= [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

dict={'x':[1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

for i in dict['x']:
    print i
print "*****************"
print dict['x'][1]
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
*****************
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dict['x'] = values
```

If you want the third line as your output. In addition, if you want your list as an output from dictionary do :

```
list(dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value_range = 1000 # or any other value
d = {'x': [1]*value_range}
print(list(d.values()))
```